# How to define a recursive union with Python typing?

Tags: python, python-typing

I am trying to define a type representing a dictionary of generally simple values but which can be nested:

```
_InfoVal: TypeAlias = str | int | ForwardRef('TemplateInfo')
TemplateInfo: TypeAlias = dict[str, _InfoVal]
```

That is, objects could be `{'myvar': "Some content", 'val': 1}` or `{'name': "A Label", 'info': {'details': "Nested Content", 'price': 123}}`. Think like, defining the type of a JSON object that can nested but somewhat simpler.

My problem is that when I do so I get an error like:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'types.UnionType' and 'ForwardRef'

Or with the simpler case not using the explicit `ForwardRef`:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'types.UnionType' and 'str'

Just in case the `|` operator only works with simpler types, I tried:

```
_InfoVal = Union(str, int, 'TemplateInfo')
```

and even:

```
_InfoVal = Union('str', 'int', 'TemplateInfo')
```

and got a much weirder error in those cases:

```
… (snip) …
    _InfoVal = Union('str', 'int', 'TemplateInfo')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 386, in __call__
    raise TypeError(f"Cannot instantiate {self!r}")
TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Union
```

Why can't I make a union involving forward types in Python 3.10.1?

Comment: Types are *instantiated* using ``(`` ``)`` but *specialised* using ``[`` ``]``. It should be ``Union[str, int, 'TemplateInfo']``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah, thanks, good catch! So the `|` syntax doesn't work but I **am** able to do a forward ref like `TemplateInfo: TypeAlias = dict[str, Union[str, int, 'TemplateInfo']]` when I use the square brackets correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I still find the behavior unexpected and weird, but fwiw I did find a workaround. By flipping around my definitions am able to split up the "union" part from the "forward reference" part:

```
TemplateInfo: TypeAlias = dict[str, '_InfoVal']
_InfoVal: TypeAlias = str | int | TemplateInfo
```

I.e. it first uses an implicit forward reference for what will be the union, and then has a "live" reference that can be used in the actual union.